# i need to output the final part of my JAVA program which is just a game over string , how can i insert it?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, logic

these is my program i need to output "game over" if the user enter the string no instead of yes, right now it only works with the yes but i dont know how to add the other option the game is suppose to ask the user for a seed , then for a number from 1 to 100 and then the user has to guees the number, once the user guesses the number it asks if it wants to play again, with option of yes or no, i have the yes but i dont know how to output the no.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessANumber_part2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Method generates a random number and per user's
        //input it prints if is to low, to high or the 
        //correct number
        guessNumber();
    }
    public static void guessNumber() {
        //Generating a seed number 
        System.out.println("Enter a seed:\n");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int seed = scanner.nextInt();
        
        //variable counts number of guesses
        int guess;//variable holds user's guess
        boolean play = true;//variable to run while 
        
        //Generating random object
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        int correctNum = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
        
        //Outer loop count the amount of guesses
        //Prompts user to play the game again
        while(play) {
            //welcome statement, getting the initial input
            System.out.println("Welcome!\n"
              + "Please enter a number between 1 and 100:");
            
            //variables 
            guess = scanner.nextInt();//saves the initial input
            int count = 1;//count the number of guesses
            
            //Inner loop outputs if the number given by the user 
            //is either to high, to low or if is the correct number 
            while( guess != correctNum) {
                if(guess < correctNum) {
                    System.out.println("Too low. Guess again:");
                }else if(guess > correctNum) {
                    System.out.println("Too high. Guess again:");
                }
                count++;// keeps count of N of guesses
                
                //welcome message and input statement 
                System.out.println("Welcome!\n"
                  + "Please enter a number between 1 and 100:");
                guess = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            
            //outer loop statement,Prompts the user to run or 
            //not run game again 
            System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed correctly!\n"
              + "You needed " + count + " guesses.\n");
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Answer \"yes\""
              + " or \"no\":");
            
            //Output statement sets play to answer "yes"
            play = scanner.next().toLowerCase().equals("yes");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Assign the input to a String like so `String input = scanner.next().toLowerCase();` then use that input in an `if` statement to either restart the game or end the program: `if (input.equals("yes")){guessNumber();} else {System.out.println("Game Over")};`

Comment: Correction `if (input.equals("yes")){System.out.println("Let's play again");} else {play = false; System.out.println("Game Over");}`